# Возвратить общую сумму из массива объектов

Tags: javascript, vue.js

**Вопрос:** в `div` с классом `target` надо отобразить сумму товаров. Как правильно перебрать массив(должно быть 2 перебора или можно в 1 пробежать) и какой метод перебора лучше использовать?

```
 let vm = new Vue({
    el: '.target',
    data: {
      cart: [
        {price: 1000, cnt: 2}, // цена и количество товара(1000*2)
        {price: 800, cnt: 3} //(800*3)
      ]
    },
    computed: {
       cartTotal() { // ((1000*2)+(800*3))
          ???
       }   
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сколько переменных нужно вывести, столько и методов. Сопровождать потом легче будет.

```js
let vm = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    cart: [{
        price: 1000,
        cnt: 2
      }, // цена и количество товара
      {
        price: 800,
        cnt: 3
      }
    ],
  },
  computed: {
    sum() {
      let result = 0;
      this.cart.forEach(el=> result += el.price*el.cnt);
      return result;
    },
    counts(){
      let result = 0;
      this.cart.forEach(el=> result += el.cnt);
      return result;
    },
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <template>
    <div style="height:300px"> <!-- style — чтобы бы виден результат в снипите. -->
      <div v-for="el in cart">
        <p>Price: {{el.price}} Count: {{el.cnt}}</p>
      </div>
      <hr>
      <p>Result: {{sum}}$, Count: {{counts}}</p>
    </div>
  </template>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо, буду пробовать